# Unable to upload to blob storage, missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk

Using the @azure/storage-blob module in the browser, it's not possible to upload to azure storage directly. It complains about a missing request header. The upload is done from within a ReactJS app running as an Office Add-in.

As required by Microsoft, CORS have been enabled on storage account for blobs.

I tried finding a way to add custom HTTP Headers however, none worked.

Here's the upload code

```
import { Credential, BlobServiceClient} from "@azure/storage-blob/browser/azure-storage-blob.min.js";

export function uploadToStorage(storageAccountName: string, storageAccountKey: string, file: SelectedFile) {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            const account = storageAccountName;
            const accountKey = storageAccountKey;
            const sharedKeyCredential = new Credential(account, accountKey);
            const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
                `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
                sharedKeyCredential
            );
            const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient("container-name");
            const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(file.name);
            const blockBlobClient = blobClient.getBlockBlobClient();
            const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.uploadBrowserData(file.data, {
                maxSingleShotSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024
              }, { "blobHTTPHeaders": { "blobContentType": file.mimeType } });
        }
        catch (error) { 
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
}
```

The error from Chrome Debugger is as follow:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://somestorageaccountsomewhere.blob.core.windows.net/blablablacontainer/Somefile-2018.5-en.docx' from origin 'https://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: any solutions found on this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75753995/angular-14-getting-cors-when-trying-to-upload-file-on-azure-blob-storage