# Angular 14: Getting CORS when trying to upload file on Azure Blob Storage

Tags: angular, file-upload, cors, azure-blob-storage

I am using "azure/storage-blob" library in Angular for uploading file to Azure Blob Storage.

- I have add CORS Rule in Azure Portal:
  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIxsK.png)
- When I try to upload a file (on Production) I got this error:
  Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'xxx' from origin 'https://xxx.azurestaticapps.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here's the request:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVF1w.png)

Here's the code I am using in Angular for uploading file, is there an implementation issue?

```
containerClient(): ContainerClient {
    return new BlobServiceClient(`https://${this.accountName}.blob.core.windows.net?${this.accessToken}`).getContainerClient(this.containerName);
  }

UploadFile() {
        const blockBlobClient = this.containerClient().getBlockBlobClient(this.file.name);
        const resp = await blockBlobClient.uploadData(this.file, {
          blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: this.file.type },
          onProgress: (progress) => {
             ...
             ...
          },
        })
}
```

I have directly enabled SAS(Blob Service SAS URL) from azure the SAS URL looks like this:
https://*****.blob.core.windows.net/[filename.mp4]?sv=2021-06-08&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2023-04-01T14:27:13Z&st=2023-02-24T06:27:13Z&spr=https&sig=****************

File upload works fine on localhost but when I tried it on production it throws CORS 403.
but when I put * in Allow-Origin it works perfectly(but I think its bad practice). I even tried clearing browser cache and used a different browser, changing Max Age (on Azure Portal) to 0, but no success.

Comment: None of those `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers belong in a request; they're _response_ headers. CORS must be configured on the server side, not the client side.

Comment: @jub0bs cors is already enabled on backend

Comment: Ok, but how? You should edit your question and explain how you've configured CORS on the backend. At any rate, including CORS response headers to your request is likely to make things worse, not better.

Comment: I am working on Angular, someone else worked on the backend.
I've seen a video in which the guy is working with Angular and uploading file to Azure Storage, and I tried the same. but in my case file uploading is working on LocalHost but when I tested on Production it is giving me CORS.
I've removed those header from the question

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issues, don't know why it was causing trouble. The problem was at Azure portal, I remove Localhost settings from Azure CORS (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIxsK.png) which resolved the issue.